# Can't get url from list of images using pupetter

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to make a scraper using puppeteer using node and everything seems to work fine. I want to get an array of objects looking like this:

```
[{
  title,
  price,
  link,
  image,
}]
```

and the following code accomplish it, I got lucky and there was a  data attribute with the image src on the page and was able to get it like this:

`img: item.querySelector('.imagebox').dataset.imgsrc,`.

Nevertheless I would like to know why  this code fails  when I want to get the `src` like this

`image: item.querySelector('img').src,`

here is the code I use and the url for the website I'm trying to scrape.

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer'

async function getHTML(url) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto(url)

  const listItem = await page.evaluate(() =>
    [...document.querySelectorAll('.aditem')].map(item => ({
      title: item.querySelector('.text-module-begin').textContent.trim(),
      price: item.querySelector('.aditem-details strong').textContent.trim(),
      link: item.querySelector('.ellipsis').href,
      img: item.querySelector('.imagebox').dataset.imgsrc,
      image: item.querySelector('img').src,
    }))
  )
  console.log(listItem)

  await browser.close()
}
```

```
const searchArea = `s-kreuzberg`
const searchParam = `bike`
const url = `https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/${searchArea}/seite:1/${searchParam}/k0l3375r5`

async function go() {
  await getHTML(url)
}

go()
```

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: So wait, the question is why you cannot get the image using the `src` attribute? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Images of the page are lazy-loaded as soon as they are scrolled into view. So we need to scroll to them and to wait a bit.
2. Even then some images are not added to the DOM due to some reason, so we need to add a check for these cases.

You can try something like this:

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer'

async function getHTML(url) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto(url)

  const listItem = await page.evaluate(async () => {
      function delay(ms) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => { setTimeout(resolve, ms) })
      }

      const items = [...document.querySelectorAll('.aditem')]
      for (const item of items) {
        item.scrollIntoView()
        await delay(100)
      }

      return items.map(item => ({
        title: item.querySelector('.text-module-begin').textContent.trim(),
        price: item.querySelector('.aditem-details strong').textContent.trim(),
        link: item.querySelector('.ellipsis').href,
        img: item.querySelector('.imagebox').dataset.imgsrc,
        image: item.querySelector('img')? item.querySelector('img').src : null,
      }));
    }
  )
  console.log(listItem)

  await browser.close()
}
const searchArea = `s-kreuzberg`
const searchParam = `bike`
const url = `https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/${searchArea}/seite:1/${searchParam}/k0l3375r5`

async function go() {
  await getHTML(url)
}

go()
```

Comment: this worked nicely! I'll keep using the `imgsrc` for performance reasons but it nice to know how to do it for lazy loaded images. 